# Autosys job failing to set job status to failed and not sending alerts

Tags: java, linux, autosys

I need my autosys job to send an email alert when java batch file configured to it end up with errorS. Unfortunately though my job is failing with error in log file autosys status is success and we are not getting any alerts. Please help me to figure out this.

Do I need to include anything in my java code?

I tried throwing exceptions from the catch block, but no luck.

Comment: Autosys looks at the return code from the process.  So run your java manually and check the value of $?.  If it is 0, autosys will always think it succeeded.  If that is the case, you need to exit your java with a return code other than 0 on error cases.

Comment: Hi Nic, I ran the job manually and saw $? value is 0. when I include System.exit(1), my build is getting failed saying [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1, any suggestions.

Comment: There's no correlation between the exit value of a process and whether an exception occurred. Just because one occurs, you don't necessarily bail by using `System.exit(n)` but you *could* set a non-zero exit code and use that *when your app exits at the usual point*

Comment: Hi Nic and g00se, Could you please give a sample java code to exit with return code other than 0. Thank you.

Comment: There's not much to it. It depends on your logic. If you get a nasty exception that you consider a sign that the program has malfunction then you can do `exitCode = -1;` (for instance) and then at the end `System.exit(exitCode);` The point is that *if your app runs to a natural end* java will automatically return success unless you tell it to do otherwise with `System.exit`

Comment: Hi g00se, Thanks for your suggestion, I tried System.exit(-1), flow is interrupted abruptly but still autosys is exiting with success code 0 and status Success. Below is my jil,

Comment: ```
insert_job: JobName    job_type: cmd
description: description
machine: XXXXXXXX
condition: s(Previousjob)
owner: XXXXXXXXX
box_name: Box name
application: XXX
permission: gx,wx,ge
alarm_if_fail: y
alarm_if_terminated: y
profile: /home/admin/.profile
send_notification: y
notification_template: Email_notification
notification_emailaddress: XXX@XXX.com
std_out_file: XXX.log
std_err_file: XXX.log
command: XXXXXXXX.sh
```

Comment: Well unfortunately, I don't know what you've done, but try the following, passing the argument 5 and then 0 with `java Exiter 5;echo $?` Then try 0: `public class Exiter {public static void main(String[] args) {int exitCode = 0;int dividend = 10;try {int result = dividend / Integer.parseInt(args[0]);}catch(Throwable t) {exitCode = 10;}finally {System.exit(exitCode);}}}`

Comment: Hi g00se,Thank you so much for the reply, I tried this but still I can see $? value as 0. I am totally confused.

Comment: My prompt, command and output: `goose@t410:/tmp$ java Exiter 0;echo $?
10` An error-free run: `goose@t410:/tmp$ java Exiter 345;echo $?
0`